AWS WAF Block Requests Without Multiple Specified Headers & Values
I am trying to build out a WAF rule that will be used to protect a public endpoint.
The rule is built as follows:

If the path matches 'some_uri'
AND NOT single header 'header_1' with size greater than 0
AND NOT single header 'header_2' with size greater than 0
Block!

In simple terms, if a request is to 'some_uri' then it must have 2 (and potentially other) headers - 'header_1' and 'header_2' - that both have some non-zero value.
I am struggling to implement it and unable to determine what the cause is.
The rule is defined with 2 seperate single header inspections, however it is not behaving as expected. Below are some of the test scenarios I have tried - the last is the confusing one...

If I make a request without either of the required headers, the request is blocked (GOOD).
If I make a request with one of the required headers without a value, the request is blocked (GOOD).
If I make a request with both required headers without a value, the request is blocked (GOOD).
However, if I make a request with both required headers where one has a value, the request is not blocked (BAD).

I cannot understand why the last scenario above is not being blocked..
From my testing it seems that the single header checks are 'combined' into a single test, rather than treated as two, independent evaluations.

This was a misunderstanding on my part about the evaluation of logic statements in WAF.
Written out, the logic statement required was:
IF request_path AND NOT (header_1 AND header_2)
Where the initial implementation was:
IF request_path AND NOT header_1 AND NOT header_2
My desired outcome was achieved by evaluating the presence and values of both header_1 and header_2 in a self contained AND statement within the rule.
